# How to ge a pixels in UIImage where alpha == 0

Tags: swift, uiimage, core-graphics

I need to get `pixels where alpha  == 0?

```
 let width = Int(img.size.width)
 let height = Int(img.size.height)

 let bitmapBytesPerRow = width
 let bitmapByteCount = bitmapBytesPerRow * height

 let pixelData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bitmapByteCount)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Why do you want this? Were you able to create one with alpha? Is there a reason to use an UnsafeMutablePointer instead of a list?

Comment: Yes I can use UnsafeMutablePointer

Comment: How can I get all pixel where alfa == 0?

Comment: That's a different question, please update it.

Comment: I will updated it? what is the solution to the problem

Comment: I'll insist in my first question: Why do you want this? If you want an array of pixels with alpha=0, I'd assume you also want to know their location, so `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` wouldn't be the appropriate structure.